# Do I need a license to use CKEditor5 to build internal admin applications?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am looking to build an internal admin application which needs to have the ability to add some rich text. I am looking to use [CKEditor5](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5) and wanted to understand how the licensing works.

Do I need to get any license if I am not looking to use any premium features right now ? And maybe in future if I decide to use premium features then only think about purchasing a license ?

Tried going through the license but wanted to be sure before using it

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as you. I want to use CKEditor for literally a single page in a large .NET based webapp, to edit some HTML in a WYSIWYG fashion.
The page is only accessed by administrators of the system who need to manage that data, and is considered 'internal' by the users, as they've had that site made specifically so they can use it to manage their system.
However, my company are the ones that made it for them, so from our perspective we're technically selling it to them.

Contacting CKEditor sales and explaining the situation, they say "Yes you need a license", but of course the sales team is going to say that...

If you read this part of the GPL FAQ (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#UnreleasedMods), it says:

> Compare this to a situation where the web site contains or links to separate GPLed programs that are distributed to the user when they visit the web site (often written in JavaScript, but other languages are used as well). In this situation the source code for the programs being distributed must be released to the user under the terms of the GPL.

Which seems to imply that if you have a website that "contains or links to CKEditor (GPLd program written in Javascript)", then the source code for the GPLd programs being distributed must be released to the user.
Since we're distributing CKEditor to the user as a Javascript file that they can easily access from the browser, surely that takes care of itself?
It doesn't mention the source of the website or any of it's proprietarily built features that it may also contain or link to, only the source of the GPLd program being distributed.

Checking this part of the FAQ (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLCompatInstaller)

> No. The installer and the files it installs are separate works. As a result, the terms of the GPL do not apply to the installation software.

One could argue that a website which references a GPLd program to be loaded is an 'installer' of that program into the browser.
Of course, it also *uses* that program, but my understand is that this is also fine under GPL, as 'using' the software doesn't constitute distributing or modifying or whatevering it...?

The strongest case for "I don't think a license is necessary to just *use* CKEditor on a website, come from this FAQ (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem)

> However, in many cases you can distribute the GPL-covered software alongside your proprietary system. To do this validly, you must make sure that the free and nonfree programs communicate at arms length, that they are not combined in a way that would make them effectively a single program.

In the case of CKEditor alongside your proprietary system, if you have a website, the website code is it's own thing, and CKEditor's code is it's own thing, and the ONLY interaction (at least most of the time) between the two, is the "CKEditor, GO!" command you use to start it from your website, and the line to tell browsers where to go get CKEditor from.
To me, that's sufficiently articulable as "arm's length".
From that perspective, CKEditor is not so much an integral part of the website, as it is an optional extra, bolted onto the side, which users may choose to block or not, as the case may be, and provides a bit of extended functionality to the page.
Especially if you're using it to replace a textarea, then not having it on the page would still allow any and all of the same operations as far as data manipulation goes, it would just be less user-friendly and require users to know more about HTML than otherwise necessary.

When it says:

> If the two programs remain well separated, like the compiler and the kernel, or like an editor and a shell, then you can treat them as two separate programs

I would argue that CKEditor as a standalone javascript bundle, and the website as a standalone whatever form it takes, and the only connection being "Here's where the CKEditor bundle is", and "CKEditor, start", is '*very* well' separated to the point that it's almost entirely disconnected.

Looking at this FAQ (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation):

> An “aggregate” consists of a number of separate programs, distributed together on the same CD-ROM or other media. The GPL permits you to create and distribute an aggregate, even when the licenses of the other software are nonfree or GPL-incompatible.

So we're also allowed to provide and distribute CKEditor from the same server as we do the proprietary website... Depending on the mechanism of communication between the two programs.

> If the modules are included in the same executable file, they are definitely combined in one program.

Which is not the case for CKEditor (usually)

> If modules are designed to run linked together in a shared address space, that almost surely means combining them into one program.

Depends what 'shared address space' means, but I'm assuming it is mostly intended for actual application binaries sharing computer address space, rather than interpreted languages like Javascript operating in the context of a webpage in a web browser.
It also depends on the definition of "designed to run together". CKEditor is designed to run with whatever wants to run it, but that's the point of it. It's not explicitly designed to run with *my* code.
Likewise, *my* code is not explicitly designed to run together with CKEditor, I could swap CKEditor out for any other WYSIWYG editor, and while I would almost certainly need to change some specific *implementation details*, the *design* would be entirely unaffected.

> By contrast, pipes, sockets and command-line arguments are communication mechanisms normally used between two separate programs. So when they are used for communication, the modules normally are separate programs.

Arguably the way websites talk to CKEditor is by running it's globally accessible constructor and giving some arguments, which in the context of Javascript vs Operating Systems, could be equated to running an available program with some arguments via the command line in a more traditional system context, perhaps?

> But if the semantics of the communication are intimate enough, exchanging complex internal data structures, that too could be a basis to consider the two parts as combined into a larger program.

For what CKEditor knows about the site using it, you basically just give it the element object for it to target for replacement, which is almost certainly not 'intimate', as this data is both simple and readily available in the browser.
On the CKEditor side, the site can provide it with all sorts of CKEditor-specific data in CKEditor-specific structures, but those data and their structures and not internal, they're part of the public and published CKEditor API.

In this FAQ (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLPlugins):

> If the main program dynamically links plug-ins, but the communication between them is limited to invoking the ‘main’ function of the plug-in with some options and waiting for it to return, that is a borderline case.

It makes the argument that invoking CKEditor as a plugin is probably 'borderline', though I'm not sure whether invoking CKEditor is actually also waiting for it to return, so that might also have an impact.

It's also in a section about plugins which assumes that the software is standalone atop the operating system, not being interpreted within the browser.
So whether it considers Javascript in the browser to be a 'plugin' for either the browser or the 'main' website functionality... Who knows...

I'm no lawyer, but I'm assuming a lawyer would probably say unofficially "Whether you need a license depends on your risk tolerance. It's not a clear-cut situation and it could go either way if it went to court. Whether it'd ever go to court in the first place is a whole other question", and officially "Just get the license, it's the only way to be sure".

Edit:

Looking at CKEditor's support pages (the main site does not have much to say but the support pages do!), they say this (https://support.ckeditor.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002452549-What-are-the-Open-Source-requirements-when-using-CKEditor-):

> Generally speaking, in Open Source, the editor's source code and its modifications must remain accessible under the same Open Source license terms, and you must keep the copyright notices in each file intact and not delete the LICENSE.md file located in the CKEditor 4 and CKEditor 5 installation folders.

And this(https://support.ckeditor.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002476685-Do-I-have-to-include-additional-terms-or-notices-in-order-to-use-the-Open-Source-license-):

> If you include CKEditor inside an application with its own copyright, the terms must clearly identify which parts of the code are not bound by your copyright. Otherwise, nothing needs to be mentioned.
>
> In any case, it is forbidden to alter or remove any of the original copyright notices and LICENSE.md file.

Both cases seem to be saying (effectively), "If you're modifying or extending CKEditor then the source for those changes needs to be just as open as CKEditor's, and if you're baking it into your own application then the same goes for that application's code as it's now effectively 'CKEditor with extra bits' regardless of how minor CKEditor's role is in said application".
Which is all well and good except that in the case where you're just *using* CKEditor on a webpage for it's primary purpose (and don't need support or premium features ofc), you're not doing any of those things, so you should be able to maintain sufficient separation between the open CKEditor source, and the closed 'rest of website' source (inasmuch as the bits of the site code that are 'closed' are server-side since anything sent to the client is arguably open by nature).